# How to use include directives with specific config files in snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

How can we define specific config files for includes in snakemake workflows?

I have a pipeline with the following structure.

The main entrypoint of the pipeline:

```
workflow/Snakefile
```

Other smk files:

```
workflow/rules/Snakefile_0.smk
workflow/rules/Snakefile_1.smk
workflow/rules/Snakefile_2.smk
```

Inside `Snakefile`, I include them using

```
include: "rules/Snakefile_0.smk"
include: "rules/Snakefile_1.smk"
include: "rules/Snakefile_2.smk"
```

I access and use the config file within these smk files, too. How can I specify config files for each smk file I include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snakemake does not support different configfiles for different rules or rule files if they are within the same main `Snakefile`. All rules of the `include: *.smk` files have access to the same `configfile` and `config` dict.

If you want to use different config-files for each `.smk` file, you can use the following workaround:
Instead of using the `include` directive, import the rules of the `.smk` files as [`module`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#modules). You can specify a different `configfile` for each module imported.